# Detrending data with nan value in scipy.signal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, trend

I have a time series dataset with some nan values in it. I want to detrend this data:

I tried by doing this:

```
scipy.signal.detrend(y)
```

then I got this error:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Then I tried with:

```
scipy.signal.detrend(y.dropna())
```

But I lost data order.

How to solve this porblem?

Comment: You *could* set the `NaN` values to be the average of the values near it. Your other main method is just to detrend the data manually; i.e., use linear least-squares on the data you *do* have and then subtract that line. Not too difficult. There's a *bunch* of functions for this: `scipy.linalg.lstsq`, `scipy.stats.linregress`, `scipy.optimize.least_squares`, `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`, `numpy.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yes that's true. Interpolation does not help me so subtracting line from data could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference there is a digital signal processing Stack site, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. I would suggest using that in the future for signal processing related questions.

---

The easiest way I can think of is to manually detrend your data. You can do this easily by computing least squares. Least squares will take into account both your `x` and `y` values, so you can drop out the `x` values corresponding to where `y = NaN`.

You can grab the indices of the non-`NaN` values with `not_nan_ind = ~np.isnan(y)`, and then do linear regression with the non-`NaN` values of `y` and the corresponding `x` values with, say, [`scipy.stats.linregress()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html):

```
m, b, r_val, p_val, std_err = stats.linregress(x[not_nan_ind],y[not_nan_ind])
```

Then you can simply subtract off this line from your data `y` to obtain the detrended data:

```
detrend_y = y - (m*x + b)
```

And that's all you need. For example with some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# create data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 500)
y = np.random.normal(0.3*x, np.random.rand(len(x)))
drops = np.random.rand(len(x))
y[drops>.95] = np.NaN # add some random NaNs into y
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image: Data with some NaN values]

```
# find linear regression line, subtract off data to detrend
not_nan_ind = ~np.isnan(y)
m, b, r_val, p_val, std_err = stats.linregress(x[not_nan_ind],y[not_nan_ind])
detrend_y = y - (m*x + b)
plt.plot(x, detrend_y)
```

[image: Detrended data]

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation about the process. It helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Only detrend non-nan parts but keep nan parts:

```
signal[np.logical_not(pd.isna(signal))] = scipy.signal.detrend(signal[np.logical_not(pd.isna(signal))])
```